# Finished task before parsing query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a spark application in AWS EMR. I have written the whole program in sparkSQL. Since the program was taking too long to complete i checked the log info and observed that executors were already executing tasks but did not find any log on the parsing the SQL commands. 
Here is a snippet of the log info.

```
17/02/12 04:32:56 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Launching task 1603 on executor id: 20 hostname: ip-10-11-203-20.ec2.internal.
17/02/12 04:32:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 179.0 in stage 32.0 (TID 1585) in 42268 ms on ip-10-11-203-20.ec2.internal (182/200)
17/02/12 04:33:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 198.0 in stage 32.0 (TID 1604, ip-10-178-43-214.ec2.internal, partition 198, NODE_LOCAL, 5295 bytes)
17/02/12 04:33:02 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Launching task 1604 on executor id: 13 hostname: ip-10-178-43-214.ec2.internal.
17/02/12 04:33:02 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 180.0 in stage 32.0 (TID 1588) in 39417 ms on ip-10-178-43-214.ec2.internal (183/200)
17/02/12 04:33:03 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 199.0 in stage 32.0 (TID 1605, ip-10-11-203-20.ec2.internal, partition 199, NODE_LOCAL, 5295 bytes)
17/02/12 04:33:03 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Launching task 1605 on executor id: 18 hostname: ip-10-11-203-20.ec2.internal.
17/02/12 04:33:03 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 183.0 in stage 32.0 (TID 1589) in 38574 ms on ip-10-11-203-20.ec2.internal (184/200)
17/02/12 04:33:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 186.0 in stage 32.0 (TID 1592) in 34329 ms on ip-10-11-203-20.ec2.internal (185/200)
17/02/12 04:33:15 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 187.0 in stage 32.0 (TID 1593) in 38905 ms on ip-10-178-43-214.ec2.internal (186/200)
```

Can anyone please explain what is going on here. Thanks.

Comment: what "log on the parsing the SQL commands" are you expecting to see? Are you sure there are any such logs in INFO level (and not DEBUG, which seems not to be printed)?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing SQL is actually quite fast in spark and if you take look at the beginning of the logs you will found parsing logs for sure.

What you can see now is just execution of query - spark divides every execution stage to tasks (to achieve parallel execution) and these `Finished task` logs just inform you that your query is in progress.